# Ubuntu won't shutdown

Tags: shutdown

A bit of background first. I use my ubuntu computer as a media center and backup server, running Ubuntu 12.04. It's scheduled to shutdown at 1am everyday.

My problem is that the computer does not shutdown. It attempts to as scheduled `sudo shutdown -h now`, but then the computer stays on after halting. It also does this when I type it into command line or use the gui. The last thing it says is

```
Will now halt

[ 945.791650] Power Down
```

The screen stays on and the computer doesn't stop, I have to use reset button or hold power button. I have already appended `acpi=force` to the grub config with no avail.

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

> For me, the solution was to upgrade the kernel. I used 4.5.3 on Ubuntu 15.10 (anything greater than this will crash the OS after login) And 4.7 RC3 works on Ubuntu 16.04.

Taken from [SirAhaz's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/789239/301745) on [Ubuntu 14.04 stuck on shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/q/508029/301745)