# system does not power off on "poweroff", just halts

Tags: shutdown

I've installed Xubuntu 15.04 on a Lenovo IdeaCentre A740 QHD with a Haswell CPU (BIOS revision 00KT19AUS) and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850A 2GB. It's mostly working, except when I do a shutdown or reboot, it doesn't actually turn off the power after quitting everything:

[image: IMG:]

So I have to click the power button to actually turn it off.

---

I've kept the Windows 8.1 installation in case there's any future firmware. Before installing Xubuntu, I turned off Fastboot from Windows, then installed Xubuntu. Unfortunately, the UEFI BIOS didn't let me change boot order so that Ubuntu actually started as default. I tried `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`, tried turning off "quickboot" (whatever that is) in BIOS, tried the Boot-Repair program from a Live Session, and tried turning off SecureBoot, but still it would just boot Windows. I ended up, with the help of EricC^^ of #ubuntu on freenode, just switching around the .efi files to trick the boot manager into thinking Ubuntu was Windows:

```
cp /boot/efi/efi/boot/bootx64.efi{,.backup}
cp /boot/efi/efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi{,.backup}
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/microsoft/boot/grubx64.efi
sudo vim /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi/20microsoft
# and changed bootmgfw.efi to bootmgfw.efi.backup
update-grub
```

I don't know if any of this has a bearing on the shutdown trouble.

EDIT: Come to think of it, the reboot from the Xubuntu installation (when I was booted through a USB drive) didn't work either.

---

What I've tried so far to get it to shut down:

- acpi=off → no difference
- acpi=force → no difference
- install proprietary Nvidia drivers → that just made X not start with the message "bbswitch: No discrete VGA device found"
- various variations on `sudo poweroff`, `sudo shutdown now`, `sudo shutdown -h now` etc.

---

Also, if I reboot instead of shutdown, I get this psychedelic lightshow on my monitor and have to long-click the power button to turn it off:

[image: reboot fun]

If it's helpful, here's a [journalctl --all output right after booting up](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11587376/) and perhaps even better: [journalctl -b -1 (journal from bootup to shutdown)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11602569/).

---

Also, perhaps related, I notice now that pressing the power button while logged in to XFCE turns the computer right off, even though I have XFCE power settings to "Ask when power button pressed" and "Do nothing" on any other buttons.

My `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` has no uncommented lines apart from the `[Login]` header.

There is a `/usr/sbin/acpid` process running as root.

---

EDIT: More revelations: Ctrl+Alt+Delete actually reboot fine from GRUB.

EDIT2: I've filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1463422) since this doesn't seem fixable with the regular tricks.

EDIT3: Solved with acpi=noirq and kernel 4.4 and newer.

Comment: I have similar issues on Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop/Server where the system hangs during shutdown/startup. My theory is that both may be related. I narrowed down the startup issue by checking `dmesg` and found that it was attempting to mount a filesystem that didn't exist and waited for a minute it before would continue booting, Also the shutdown issues were related a mount because if I shutdown my desktop with an open NFS connection to my server without forcefully un-mounting it will hang. I am not sure if these issues are related to your problem but I thought I'd bring them up just encase.

Comment: M. Lindman's comment makes a good point obliquely.  There's a log that shows you in detail what's going on.  Read it with `journalctl --all`.  [edit] your answer and show it to people if you want help understanding it.

Comment: JdeBP: added, but from what I can tell, journalctl only gives info from *this* bootup – is there a way to make it keep previous ones?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159221/

Comment: Thanks JdeBP, wondered why those logs weren't stored :) I added a new link to the bottom of the question, though I can't find anything suspicious myself.

Comment: post the content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

Comment: What does sudo shutdown -P now act like ? That's what I personally use to poweroff my machine every time

Comment: Serg, the same. (And man shutdown says `-P` is the default.)

Comment: My best guess based on the info provided is a buggy UEFI BIOS. Is there an update?

Comment: Possibly related http://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding

```
acpi=noirq
```

to the kernel boot parameters. This lets it poweroff on shutdown/restart (tested with kernels 4.4 and 4.7rc5).

It seems to suspend too, but unfortunately does *not* resume from suspend on pressing the power button.

This has worked fine for over three months now on the A740, so I'm calling this solved.

Comment: I'm glad my option A) worked for you! :-)

Comment: As in "wait and hope"? What I actually did was report it as bug in the Ubuntu linux package, trying some newer mainline releases, then when that didn't solve anything I reported it upstream, first to the wrong component https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118401 , then got sent to ide/ahci, and after some e-mail exchanges and trying to get useful debug output http://marc.info/?t=146296312800002&r=1&w=2 and trying different options suggested there, found the one that worked. Simply waiting and upgrading doesn't solve it, the grub settings need to be edited.

Comment: Regardless, I'm glad you got it sorted. Whether it was A or B  :-)

Answer (score 4):

My best guess based on the info provided is a buggy UEFI BIOS. digging through the kernel bugs for Haswell I found a possible workaround. Try using `xhci_hcd.quirks=262144` as a boot option or Disabling xhci in the UEFI.

The only other options I can think of are as follows:

A) Wait and hope that either the kernel development team or Lenovo comes up with an update that resolves the problem.

B) Contact [Lenovo Support](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/supportphonelist) and push for a BIOS update that resolves the problem or encourage others with the same problem to subscribe to your bug report. This may or may not be any more effective than A.

C) Modify the [BIOS](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/) or the [kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) yourself until you reach the desired result (Not for the faint of heart). I'm not recommending this course of action, only including it for completeness. Modifying the BIOS can easily leave you with an unbootable system with a voided warranty. You should also read carefully the reasons for and against compiling your own kernel in the aforementioned linked document.

Source: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66171#c118

Comment: That's for Broadwell systems ( https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/lenovo-a-series-all-in-ones/lenovo-a740-all-in-one/downloads/DS102570 ), mine's a Haswell (BIOS revision 00KT19AUS)

Comment: Edited new information into question for you.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Note: It appears that Christopher M. Penalver  came to the same false conclusion I did regarding the BIOS. You may wish to bring them up to speed on your reported bug.

Comment: Got my hopes up, but unfortunately the quirk thing didn't work either :-( And I can't find any XHCI settings in BIOS anywhere.

Comment: (also tried the 8192 and 270336 quirks, to no avail)

Comment: XHCI settings are USB related - I hope that helps you find them in your BIOS. If not, contact Lenovo customer service at 1 (855) 253-6686 and ask about where to find them or if they have a BIOS update in the works. All the best!

Comment: Yeah, the only USB related setting I found was one to "disable USB", which I don't want to do since I don't know how I'd turn it back on again then :-)

Comment: (Lenovo support said they'd notify the BIOS people, I don't feel to confident though.)

Comment: I wish you the best of luck! I think I'll continue to build my own systems rather than rely on major manufacturers.

Answer (score 2):

After ferreting through the system files I saw a few warning about the BIOS. I checked Intel's website and there was an upgrade available that seemed to solve an issue of overlapping memory addresses. Not obviously the same but my logs indicated that various sectors of my BIOS were returning unexpected values, which did not prevent the kernel from starting but obviously was not good. The issue was not apparent until the kernel stopped using `upstart` and started using `systemd`.

I downloaded the updated BIOS and applied it and now my system turns off as expected.

Comment: What system/BIOS was this? (Lenovo hasn't yet released an updated BIOS for my processor architecture.)

Answer (score 0):

What `cat /etc/default/halt` says? Try `halt -p`.

You can also edit `/etc/init.d/halt` and remove this lines:

```
if [ "$INIT_HALT" = "HALT" ]
then
  poweroff=""
fi
```

below

```
poweroff="-p"
```

Comment: `halt -p` is no different, it still doesn't shut down completely.

Comment: oh, and /etc/default/halt says `HALT=poweroff`. But shouldn't `halt -p` or `poweroff`  or `shutdown now` still work regardless of what's in there?

Answer (score 0):

From your Kernel Logs (Screenshot) I have a hunch that unattended-upgrades might be the cause of your issue. There have been [several bug reports](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=unattended+upgrades+shutdown+incomplete&oq=un&aqs=chrome.2.69i59j69i60j69i59l2j69i60l2.8704j0j4&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) on this years ago, but they have not been resolved. A temporary fix to this would be to disable automatic updates by updates, but we will keep it as a last resort. But first of all, we will try a manual upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If this did not solve your issue, and the upgrade went without any errors or warnings, wee will try digging a bit more deep to see if we can find out what is causing the issue. You could get a lead by inspecting the contents of `/var/log/unattended-upgrades`. If you could figure out which update is causing the issue, you could blacklist the update by modifying `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`.

If it still does not solve the issue, you can temporarily  remove the package, to confirm if it is the cause:

```
sudo apt-get remove unattended-upgrades
```

I recommend that you reinstall it even if it solved your issue. If this is the case bring back the the bug report with more information so that the developers can solve your issue.

Warning: If you choose to disable automatic update and then don't manually update your system, you may be at risk from security and stability view point.

Comment: This is a fresh install – `autoremove` and `dist-upgrade` have "0 to upgrade, 0 to remove" etc, and /var/log/unattended-upgrades is empty: `$ wc -c  < /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log` gives `0`

Comment: Also, there are no programs in `/lib/systemd/system-shutdown`, so there are no services that should be called when I type [poweroff](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-halt.service.html). And removing `unattended-upgrades` completely had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and after days a lowly rated fanswer from this forum did the trick: [Ubuntu 14.04 stuck on shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown/789239#789239?newreg=eed923da78d14926a74bb187cb0decef)

> For me, the solution was to upgrade the kernel. I used 4.5.3 on Ubuntu
>   15.10 (anything greater than this will crash the OS after login) And 4.7 RC3 works on Ubuntu 16.04.

Now works perfectly :-)

Comment: That didn't work for my system. As the bug reports show, I already tried quite a lot of 4.7 kernels – these just made it impossible to boot! After reporting upstream and debugging help from kernel list, the workaround to both my issues (booting at all, and powering off on shutdown) was `acpi=noirq` http://askubuntu.com/a/794739/25639

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it definitely has something to do with ACPI. My system exhibits this exact behaviour if and only if I pass acpi=off in Linux 4.20-rc3 for kernel development purposes. If your ACPI was enabled at first, then there is a fair chance that the ACPI implementation in the BIOS was buggy. I see you said a kernel upgrade helped. But a BIOS upgrade may have done the trick, also.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.  Your suggestion relating to the BIOS merely indicates a possible solution, one which it would appear you haven't actually tried.  In fact, the OP indicated that he had solved his issue by "adding acpi=noirq to the kernel boot parameters".

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and believe that it is related to the UEFI boot. On an Acer Aspire V 11, originally Windows 8, I have done a fresh install of OpenSUSE Leap 15.0 with EFI boot and secure boot set to "disabled" in the BIOS. Now the shutdown, reboot and suspend work correctly.

Previously, I was using Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and most recently 18.10 under legacy boot and they all suffered the same problem. I also tried Fedora 24, OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and OpenSUSE 42.2, all with the same problem.

I also tried Ubuntu 18.10 with EFI boot and secure boot enabled but got a non-bootable device error. I did not try EFI boot with secure boot disabled.

Answer (score 0):

We bought a cheap mini-pc with Intel board for a project. It was shipped with Win7, I reinstalled Debian 10 for deep customization in the project. On every reboot/poweroff, it has a high chance to stuck at the end of poweroff stage with systemd's "Watchdog didn't stop" as the last message.

I checked the BIOS setup screen, there is an option, to specify system type. Win7/Android/Win10. After switched to `Android`, it can reboot/poweroff without problem.

PS: I did try `reboot=pci` `reboot=bios` parameters, but none of them worked. I wish I've checked BIOS for ACPI related settings ealier.

Hope this helps in some case.

Comment: Seems like you found a good solution to a completely different problem – perhaps you could add it as a separate question with a self-answer, then others with your problem could be helped by your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Your hardware might not support software shutdown.  I've had that happen before, and the way to test is this:

```
sudo poweroff
```

If that does not shutdown the hardware, it's a hardware issue and not software.

Comment: As the question states, I've tried that to no avail. But GRUB manages the software reboot just fine (not sure how to test poweroff there) while Windows 8.1 does the software poweroff and reboot just fine on this hardware. It seems like a kernel issue, so I've filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1463422).

Comment: upvote for filing a bug report.

Comment: -1 Because I find otherwise. It ends with `systemd-shutdown[1]: Powering off.` The machine turned off just fine with 12.04 and 14.04, but not a fresh install of 16.04.

Answer (score -1):

1. Restart then F2
2. Go to configuration and disable xHCI
3. Save and exit

Don't think about it just trust me and do it :)

Comment: I can't find any XHCI settings in BIOS anywhere. I can turn off all of USB, but that's not an option for me.

Comment: this will not turn all usb it will only turn usb3