# Can't boot into Ubuntu 15.10 without 'idle

Tags: grub2, uefi, acpi, grub-efi, idle

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10(EFI 64bit) on MSI GS40 laptop, which has Intel Skylake processor and Nvidia's dedicated GPU.

I couldn't boot to Ubuntu's installation stage without giving GRUB's boot option 'nomodeset' and 'idle=nomwait'.

I searched throughout the internet, found out that I should install Nvidia's proprietary driver to boot without 'nomodeset', and solved that, but still I can't boot without 'idle=nomwait'.

I finished upgrading whole packages and it still can't. I searched again and I found that this option is related to Intel's C-State policy.

I could't progress further from here. Since I saw 'idle=nomwait' disables Intel's C-State function, I want to boot without this because it's laptop that I use outside. So I really have no choice but this, questioning to you guys. Please help me!

PS. Reinstalling it and going into installation screen or live mode, it says

```
ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected
```

, but I don't know any clue about it.

Comment: Fixing this type of problem often requires kernel changes. Although Ubuntu provides patched kernels from time to time, such a fix may require an update to a new version, such as 16.04, which is due out on April 21, with a 4.4 kernel, rather than the 4.2-series kernel used in 15.10. That said, I don't know that this pattern will hold true for your specific problem. Maybe there's already a fix available for you. If not, though, keep your eye on 16.04. You might even try the final beta, which is [already available.](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/)

Comment: @Rod Smith, I followed your advice and installed 16.04, but this problem is still the same. I also found that it seems unable to hibernate or shutdown with Intel Graphics, only with the Nvidia's one enabled it can do those.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you [file a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: When you say "unable to shutdown" – is it similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/632591/system-does-not-power-off-on-poweroff-just-halts ? And what kernel versions have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to get Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my msi gs40 as well... Did you try the recommendations on this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2284315&page=2).  I still haven't gotten it fully working yet either, but the OP on that thread seems to suggest he has.