# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I deleted `"quiet splash"` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the GRUB config file.

And when I reboot with the command line, I can see the commands until it reaches `target reached restarting now`

And then.... nothing, it freezes there. So it is not possible to shut down.

It is a dual boot of Win10 with Ubuntu 16.04

I had a similar problem on launch but I fixed it on adding `acpi=off` after pushing the <kbd>E</kbd> key in the GRUB menu.

**EDIT**

I changed `acpi=off` to `acpi=noirq` and this gave me a freeze on restart and when I did force shutdown and restart it gave me a purple screen with nothing. I had to edit again from the GRUB menu to put it back to `acpi=off`

[image]

What else can I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This started happening on my Ubuntu machine after I extended the Ubuntu partition size.

The solution is to boot from a Ubuntu live-session (boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu", it may work on an installed Ubuntu too).

Then:

1. Make sure you are connected to the Internet
2. Open a new Terminal, and type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```

This should repair your GRUB and help the OS shutdown correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  My machine keeps hanging on shutdown after I try to enable hibernate.  This fixes it.

Comment: I will validate your answer as it seems to have helped some users. I will give it a try. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try `acpi=noirq`

like the answer to this question: [acpi power off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632591/system-does-not-power-off-on-poweroff-just-halts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it says I need to add it to boot kernel parameter. But where I can find this? and where should I add it?

Comment: > I had a similar problem on launch but I fixed it on adding "acpi=off" after pushing the E key and added the line. <


do the similar thing and replace the entry `acpi=off`.

Comment: it doesn't work; my splashscreen is like empty, purple colored like the ubuntu splashcreen and nothing happens. I had to restart and to replace again with acpi=off. Im running kernel 4.4

Comment: `acpi=off` can be dangerous to the hardware, because of turning off the fan. `noacpi` could be one more try. Both are described here in german [acpi kernel settings](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bootoptionen/)

Comment: I added an image to the ticked, to see if I placed things in the right places

Comment: It says in the screenshot: run `update-grub`... did you do that, too? I cannot further assist you here, sorry for that! I have not hold of a ubuntu box right now...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Btrfs?

I had very long shutdowns of tens of minutes after moving my 8 data disks from ext4 to Btrfs. I worked-around it by adding `nocache_space` to the mount options for my Btrfs mount points in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 0):

I too had been experiencing random freezes after switching from 14LTS to 16LTS. I ran memtest86 and disk check but all passed. Just a couple of days ago out of exasperation I decided **to revert from kernel 4.9 to kernel 4.4**. Since then I've not had any hanging or freezing. In fact, it also seems to me my laptop runs cooler. Don't know why or any details but so far it is working for me.