# System that worked fine with 12.04 LTS will not power off with 16.04

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, grub2, power-management, shutdown

I decided to upgrade to a new SSD and 16.04 LTS as I have been running 12.04 LTS and it's out of date.

The install went fine, but the system which was working fine with 12.04 will not power off on shutdown with 16.04.

I came across this article [system does not power off on "poweroff", just halts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632591/system-does-not-power-off-on-poweroff-just-halts?newreg=69cb4b0d1e654feb9383a9f6b2322f37) which seems similar, but setting acpi=noirq does not seem to help.

Any suggestions?  The MB is an Intel DB33BU; and as noted the system had no boot/shutdown issues with 12.04.

Thanks
sk

Comment: Drop down to `tty` by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F2` and then shutdown using `systemctl poweroff -i`. Post a screenshot of the output. Also, here you will be able to find out the reason why your system isn't shutting down.

Comment: Hi, I tried that command; no screen output.  The screen goes to the Ubuntu shutdown GUI image and freezes there.

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/33420/119531) to disable splash screen. You can re-enable it again by reversing what was given in the answer. Then, try the above command

Comment: @Raphael;   I took a screenshot with my phone when the system stopped.  https://app.box.com/s/6ll16czasoupmn926fizbob4h732nnd9

Comment: Hi, any update or suggestions?

Comment: Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry) to set an older kernel as the default kernel and check if it works. If yes, then wait for the next kernel update as it might be a problem with the kernel.