# 15.10 on Asus Zenbook: Hanging at shutdown with power plugged in

Tags: power-management, 15.10, shutdown, asus

I have an ASUS Zenbook UX305 and I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it. Everything works fine, except that when I have the power cable plugged in and do a shutdown I think it must hang just as it's about to turn off.

After shutdown, everything appears to have turned off (including all leds) but if I leave the power cable plugged in and press the power on button, an led comes on but it never does anything else.

If I reboot rather than shutdown, or if I shutdown with the power cable unplugged, or if I shudown and then remove the power cable before trying to turn back on, I don't appear to have any problems. The problem only seems to occur when I have the power plugged in the whole time.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update: I've tried to set some settings in Grub as in http://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown but still no luck, My problem appears to be slightly different, in that the computer appears to shutdown completely but doesn't.