# Ubuntu hangs on shutdown and restart

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I have a `Lenovo B50-10`. I installed Ubuntu 14.04. When I want to shutdown the computer Ubuntu hangs. The hard drive turns off but the display shows me the Ubuntu logo with the dots. When I want to restart the display turns black and the computer doesn't do anything.

I have already tried a lot of things (modifiying the boot options etc) mentioned in threads with the same problem. Unfortunately none of them worked for me. I really don't know what to do also because it's my first linux. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So , it seems like it goes into system halt , which is where the system stops, every process is closed, but peripherals are still powered on. Try opening terminal, with Ctrl + Alt + T shortcut and type in `sudo shutdown -P now` , where `-P` is power - off option. See if that works properly

Comment: okay I did as you said. But the same problem occurs.

Comment: OK, in that case it's a different issue. See if this helps : http://askubuntu.com/q/508029/295286

Comment: alright, I think I already went there and tried the solutions. But thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I went to bios and set "OS optimized default" to "enabled" and hit "Load default setting". Then save and exit.