# My ubuntu 16.04 does not shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown

I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 7 in my pc and all the features in it are working fine but when I click on shutdown it gets stuck on the violet screen with ubuntu written on it and even the dots stop blinking.
I then tried to clean install it again but the problem still persists.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: click shutdown on this screen click **escape button** and edit your question with what you see

Comment: i pressed every damn key for 40 minutes nothing happened

Comment: take a look at, it seems to be the same problem... http://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo shutdown` OR `sudo reboot` if you want to restart, in a terminal.

if you cannot access terminal for some reason, then press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` then login using your user name and password, then use `sudo shutdown` again.

if you want to return back to your desktop screen press `Ctrl+Alt+F7`

Comment: tried that too didnt work

Comment: while in the screen you posted, did you try pressing the UP or DOWN key which will then show whats going on in the background.. And perhaps show an error somewhere.

Answer (score -2):

The issue could be related to nvidia driver if you have one. Try to update nvidia drivers like that:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This solution worked for me. 
Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/150121/571419