# System does not shut down properly (on any Linux distro)

Tags: nvidia, dell

I have a Dell inspiron 3542(i5-4210U,Nvidia geforce 820m)

When I try to shutdown, the screen freezes but the CPU and internal stuff stops.

I can shut down fine in Windows, but whatever distro I try, Linux systems will not shut down correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Inspiron 7559 ( i5-6300HQ, Nvida geforce 960M).

After installing Ubuntu 14.04, I had a similiar issue. The CPU would halt on Shutdown or Suspend, requiring me to hold the power button to turn it off.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/792086/658448) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/720577/658448) answer helpful, but it only worked once.

So I wrote a script to edit that config file and update grub:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet splash/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off/g' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub
```

Then I added that script to my Startup Applications so it runs every time I open Ubuntu. I haven't had any issues since.