# Ubuntu 17.04 Not Shutdown

Tags: shutdown, cinnamon

My ubuntu is not shutting down. Shutdown is Frozen

[image]

[Freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlaLo.jpg)

Note : grub default `acpi=force` or `reboot=force`, EFI not run.

- System : MSI GE60 2PC Apache
- Graphic Drivers : Nvidia-375(ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa repo)
- Prime-Select : Intel
- Ubuntu : 17.04 x64 UEFI

Comment: At that point, press ESC. You will probably see a number of error messages. Please add these to your question.

Comment: esc not run. screen is freezing.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlaLo.jpg screen is freeze

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/1388530 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown

Comment: i try. Not run. not power off pc

Comment: The same here. I am using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 and it does not shut down. The first time I shut down I read something about [plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth), maybe the issue has to do with that. I do not know really. I have a MSI GE62VR Apache pro

Comment: I have just shut down pressing the key `Esc` and I could see that the system was trying to stop 6 tasks during 5min on a continuous loop. After that the system shut down. Maybe that is your problem as well. Try to wait 5min at least and check if the system shut down

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`. Instead of

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Write this to check if you can see some error

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="plymouth:debug"
```

Or just remove the splash screen

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

After each modification run this on the console

```
$ sudo update-grub
```