# Slow shutdown(2 minutes) for ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, performance

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

When I turn off my computer it takes 1 minute and 45 seconds to turn off.

It use to take 10 seconds. I'm not sure what happened, I'm also a very novice user. I'm not familiar with the terminal or any special commands, currently learning.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you close all programs prior to shutdown?  Any external disks connected. Did you install some new hard- or software. Did you force a powerdown... anything you remember may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I do have an external hard drive but i unplugged it to check and that didn't change the time. I honestly don't remember, this happened a little while ago. I do have a ssd that i use on my computer. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: The shutdown process is not really logged but, like you said, it is usually finished in a few seconds.  And honestly I never had to look into it. I did find this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown  Not 100% the same but maybe it helps. Let me know your findings. Later today I can research some more if needed.

Comment: Hi Bryce. Funny thing happened. My Ubunto 17.04, running as VM in VM Player took a long time to shutdown. The system reported it was waiting 1min30 for LightDM to shutdown. Perhaps you have a lead with this...

Answer (score 0):

Two years late is better than at all :p

Coincidentally, this was solved for me after I'd configured my GPU (Graphics card), try it, it might work.