# Ubuntu 14 Server on Mac Pro will not Power Off on Shutdown

Tags: 14.04, grub2, shutdown

I have tried this [Ubuntu 14.04 stuck on shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown)

But it did not help. The `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` setting actually wasn't there for me so I added it. Now I get the 'splash' screen (server style) on shutdown but still the computer does not power off.

When I run `sudo shutdown now`

Ubuntu stops all services and goes into a single user mode with a `root` user prompt on the screen, but does not power off the machine.

This is a Mac Pro 2008 machine (EFI).
It is a new installation from this iso `ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64+mac.iso`

Thanks.

Comment: try it with -h (`sudo shutdown -h now`) where -h means halt-power after shutdown.  shutdown strictly means the OS itself shuts down, not the hardware (*unless you add -h or --poweroff*)

Comment: yes that worked, I never knew that. It seems like other systems I've used power off without that argument. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of commands that will turn off your system, including `halt`, `poweroff` and of course `shutdown`.

Most of us with small modern machines expect the hardware to go off, but on larger machines the power usage drop (on a large machine turning off) can be a pain, not to mention the wear of powering off then powering back on hardware so the halt of power doesn't occur unless specified.

With shutdown just add a `-h` to cause power down of hardware (after OS is safely shutdown)

`sudo shutdown -h now`